# Create a table on a filegroup other than the default

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, filegroup

The title is clear enough, I created a new Filegroup "ArchiveFileGroup":

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase
ADD FILEGROUP ArchiveFileGroup;
GO
```

I want to create a table called : arc_myTable in order to store old data from this one : myTable

I used the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].acr_myTable(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [label] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
)on ArchiveFileGroup
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way, I don't know where the FileGroup is created to check if it contains the table.

Comment: If you're using SSMS, it will show the filegroup of a table. In the object explorer table properties, select "storage".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily check with this [sql query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/01/sql-server-list-all-objects-created-on-all-filegroups-in-database/):

```
SELECT o.[name], o.[type], i.[name], i.[index_id], f.[name]
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o
ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
AND o.type = 'U' -- User Created Tables
GO
```

Just add:

```
AND f.name = ArchiveFileGroup
```

to see everything in your new filegroup or:

```
AND o.name = acr_myTable
```

to see where your table is located.

If you never added a file to your filegroup, then I would expect an error but you didn't include either an error message or anything saying you did create a file.  If you did not, I suggest starting at the [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if needed.

The OP found the [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1397838.aspx?The%20filegroup%20comn_data%20has%20no%20files%20assigned%20to%20it%20sql) helpful trying to create a new file in his filegroup.

Comment: Indeed when I checked the properties of the FILEGROUP , it had 0Mb no file was added. I thought when the FILEGROUP was created the file is added by default. I have no idea how to add this file. I'll check the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: @GSDa, are you sure? cause per your post I see you already created a table on that file group. BTW, is it a empty table? if yes, then it may be.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, you're right it was empty, I wasn't able to add a row. the error said that the filgroup has no file added.

Comment: @GSDa, You may want to post that as separate question (if you want).

Comment: I found a solution, It may help others here's how to add a file to an existing FILEGROUP http://forums.asp.net/t/1397838.aspx?The+filegroup+comn_data+has+no+files+assigned+to+it+sql

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sys.filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187782.aspx) to see all the created file groups in your server like

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.filegroups
```

See here for more information [List All Objects Created on All Filegroups](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/01/sql-server-list-all-objects-created-on-all-filegroups-in-database/)

Answer (score 1):

It is old post. Want to add information, it might help somebody in future.

`sp_help <table_name>`

You can see the filegroup, on which the table is created.

Answer (score 0):

NB. You can check by Right-clicking on the table then select properties. on the storage you can see to which the filegroup the new table is belonging

> In your case:
>   It will create the table on the default filegroup, not on the new filegroup you created. A filegroup is logical and used to create a secondary file. ex. if you need to create the table on a different location than the default drive, you have to define fileName for the new filegroup.

```
ALTER DATABASE [db] ADD FILEGROUP [NewFileGroup]

ALTER DATABASE [db] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'NewFile', FILENAME = N':D\..\Newfile.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ) TO FILEGROUP [NewFileGroup]
```

GO