# Is it possible under MS SQL Server to separate different objects onto different Files (eg. "Tablespaces")

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

just a general question regarding MS SQL Server:

1. Is it possible to separate "Marketing" tables/objects from "Inventory" tables/objects?
2. Is it possible to separate Table-objects from Index-objects?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Im just trying to answer the questions above, that is all. I just want to knoww if its possible

Comment: The answer is "yes" - but they're called "filegroups", not "tablespaces" - and I'm unsure about the specific differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087614/create-a-table-on-a-filegroup-other-than-the-default - however generally speaking, unless you know you need to, and you can point to the specific guidance or instructions in the documentation that says you should, you shouldn't.

Comment: this isn't a mysql question, removing tag

Comment: Good day @AliAraien, in order to answer these question you must clarify what is the meaning of "separate" which you speak about. Do you mean for example separate physically to different file behind the scenes, do you mean separate logically with privileges to different users, or maybe separate virtually for administrative tasks and so on... This sound like a interview question which meant to hear how you answer and not only what you answer.  It is more of a philosophic question at this point until you clarify the definition of "separate" you mean and convert it to a focused technical question.

Comment: Maybe you should consider different [schemas](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-create-schema/#:~:text=What%20is%20a%20schema%20in,always%20belongs%20to%20one%20database.)