# how to transfer data from one sql server pc to another sql server pc?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have two server named server-A and server-B. both servers have sql server 2008 and have same editions. i need to transfer table data from server-A to server-B. how to solve this? will it possible to with different editions

Comment: if you can clarify whether both the server are on same pc?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Take a Backup of the Database and restore it

Option 2:

Generate a Script and execute on pc 2

Helpful Links

**[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698310/backup-a-single-table-with-its-data-from-a-database-in-sql-server-2008)**

**[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680552/table-level-backup)**