# Generate a dynamic sql script or backup of particular items of data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am working on a project with multi users who can store their individual data. I am confused on how to proceed if a user wants to save his own data from multiple tables as a backup and retrieve it any time if the data is lost or corrupted if anyone has any clue on how to do that would be a great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backup a single table with its data from a database in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698310/backup-a-single-table-with-its-data-from-a-database-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot backup specific tables to a **.bak** file, but you can export them to a CSV or script them out. What you can do if you want to back up specific tables is move them into a separate **file group** and back up that file group.

See [Back Up Files and Filegroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-files-and-filegroups-sql-server) for the documentation.

Below is an example.

```
--Back up the files in SalesGroup1.
BACKUP DATABASE Sales
   FILEGROUP = 'SalesGroup1',
   FILEGROUP = 'SalesGroup2'
   TO DISK = 'C:\MySQLServer\Backups\Sales\SalesFiles.bak';
GO
```